# How can I pass java -jar arguments in a batch file?

Tags: java, batch-file, svn

How can I pass java -jar arguments in a batch file ? 
Code below doesn't work:

```
set classpath = c:/users/abc/desktop/project/trunk/.CLASSPATH

java -jar java_file.jar "%classpath%"
```

( the java jar file needs to take the location of the .CLASSPATH file as the argument ) .
In my main batch file, classpath variable takes the value depending on which project is checked out from the SVN .

Hope my question is clear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because your `set` command has spaces around the `=`. Remove them and it works.

What you have there now essentially means that an environment variable `classpath<SPACE>` is set to the given value which *starts* with a space. Therefore, the environment variable `%classpath%` (without the space in the variable name) doesn't exist at all.

Comment: @Gaurav.dwrg you should accept Joey's answer if it helped you.